# modal prevent click outside not work using javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

i have a try with my code but not working , modal still click using mouse, here some code

My Modal :

```
<!-- modal -->

<div id="my-modal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(229, 229, 229, 0); background: #FF5722; color: #fff;">
            <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> Danger</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="background: #FF5722; color: #fff;">
            Hello World!
        </div>
         <div class="modal-footer" style="background: #FF5722; border-top: 1px solid rgba(229, 229, 229, 0);">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#my-modal').modal('show');
    $('#my-modal').modal({
      backdrop : 'static',
      keyboard : false
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$('#my-modal').modal('show');
$('#my-modal').modal({
  backdrop : 'static',
  keyboard : false
})
```

...to this:

```
$('#my-modal').modal({
  backdrop : 'static',
  keyboard : false
});
$('#my-modal').modal('show');
```

You could even omit `$('#my-modal').modal('show');` entirely.